# String.split() not working as intended

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I'm trying to split a string, however, I'm not getting the expected output.

```
String one = "hello 0xA0xAgoodbye";
String two[] = one.split(" |0xA");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(two));
```

Expected output: `[hello, goodbye]`

What I got: `[hello, , , goodbye]`

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance! ^-^

Comment: for debugging regular expressions you can use something like https://regex101.com/r/1kdsOe/1 this link will show you it matches thrice. hence the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result is caused by multiple consecutive matches in the string. You may wrap the pattern with a grouping construct and apply a `+` quantifier to it to match multiple matches:

```
String one = "hello 0xA0xAgoodbye";
String two[] = one.split("(?:\\s|0xA)+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(two));
```

A `(?:\s|0xA)+` regex matches 1 or more whitespace symbols or `0XA` literal character sequences.

See the [Java online demo](https://ideone.com/OaUB6y).

*However*, you will still get an empty value as the first item in the resulting array if the `0xA` or whitespaces appear at the start of the string. Then, you will have to remove them first:

```
String two[] = one.replaceFirst("^(?:\\s|0xA)+", "").split("(?:\\s+|0xA)+");
```

See [another Java demo](https://ideone.com/MHb138).

Comment: How can I make this work if my string is just ``hello 0xA0xA``, without "goodbye". When I use this regex, the array I get is ``[hello, ]``, but I just want ``[hello]``

Comment: No idea what your input looks like - see [this demo](https://ideone.com/vm7Umu). I get `[hello]`.

Comment: Here's my input: ``HELLO 1.0 1 A1B2C3 0 1 0xD0xA0xD0xA`` and this is my regex (in java code): ``(?:\\s|0xD0xA)+``. When I split, I want to get ``[HELLO, 1.0, 1, A1B2C3, 0, 1]``, but I'm getting ``[HELLO, 1.0, 1, A1B2C3, 0, 1, ]``

Comment: The input and pattern are different here. Note that if your delimiters are whitespaces and `0xD0xA` you will also expect `hellothisisatest` in your output array. See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/1PrGyh).

Comment: Ok, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/zd7FTH). Are you sure you are not passing any additional parameters to `.split()`? It looks like you are [passing `-1` as the second argument](https://ideone.com/q53fzs).

Comment: That's weird... I just checked, and I'm sure split is called with only one argument, the regex.

Comment: Then it is possible that your string actually ends with some unprintable non-whitespace char, like `\uFFFD`. Please check your *actual* string [in this utility](http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/) and share the code points you have there.

Comment: I redirected stdou to a .txt file to get the actual string, but it seemed fine. However, the last element of the array return by ``.split`` is a million ``\00`` characters. Is this happening because I'm creating the string out of a byte[], which is mostly empty at the time?

Comment: Use `String#trim()` to remove them before running split.

Comment: Thank you, ``.trim()`` solved the problem. Thanks for all the help, love you :3

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like to treat consecutive delimiters as one, you could modify your regex as follows:

```
"( |0xA)+"
```

This means "a space or the string `"0xA"`, repeated one or more times".

Comment: Love you :) Still need to wait 8min to add your anwer as accepted though :c

Comment: @Tirafesi: With this solution, you will still have an empty item if the match happens to be at the string start. Try the solution with `String one = " 0xA0xA hello 0xA0xAgoodbye";`.

Answer (score 2):

`(\\s|0xA)+` This will match one or more number of space or `0xA` in the text and split them